# ImportError: No module named channels.asgi

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have the following content in `wsgi.py` file:

```
import os
import sys

from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/home/project')
sys.path.append('/home/project/Project_Web_Main')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Project_Web_Main.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

but I have the following error when importing:
`from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer`

`ImportError: No module named channels.asgi`

Comment: Either channels.asgi does not exist or the file for channels.asgi is not located in your PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: @bigwillydos `echo $PYTHONPATH` does not show me output

Comment: there is nothing to show

Comment: this is not a duplicate question !!!! its related to a specifc topic and not answered anywhere. wtf

Comment: If you are having this issue, it might be because your `asgi.py` is not updated for channels2. Please check that according to the documentation here: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html